How to run 1/2” pex to manifold from old trunk and branch system?
I have old quest pipes that leak so I am repiping my home to pex, the issue I am having is how to repipe my trunk and branch system 3/4” pipe to a central location to 1/2” pipe… I will need more holes through the horizontal 2x4 to fit all the 1/2” hoses for the manifold.
The horizontal 2x4 currently have holes for the 3/4”. Don’t believe I can drill any more holes through the 2x4 or am I wrong and the 2x4 is only for framing up drywall beingnits horizontal?

If you fully remove any polly pipe the Pex will fit in any hole already drilled.  Or do I not understand the question?

Maybe I didn’t explain it clearly, so I have a hot and cold 3/4” main pipes that branches out to 1/2” pipes. I now want to make full runs with 1/2” pipes a total of 13 1/2” pipes through my crawl space to my garage on a manifold. All 13 lines will not fit through the two 3/4” pipe holes…. I would prefer to run the lines in a central location wall. My home is only 1600sq ft a small home with a crawl space. The wall it’s currently going through is load bearing interior wall. 16 space between the 2x4. The 3/4” pipes currently go throug a horizontal 2x4 that runs through to the crawl space

I believe the correct term is the bottom header? Or the bottom frame of the wall 2x4. It has holes for two 3/4” pipes but I now want to run 13 1/2” pipes to replace the 3/4 main lines.

This isn't an answer (which is why it's a comment): have you considered logic plumbing instead of a manifold? This does require the use of PEX-A rather than PEX-B, but in exchange you spend less on pipe and can add hot water recirculation later if you want.
